# How to reuse Postgres variables declared using 'WITH' operator

Tags: postgresql, with-statement

i need to delete records from two tables, but i cannot perform it consistently, because of after deletion from first table there will be no data to delete from second.
I have tried following:

```
WITH person_ids AS(select person_id from application_person 
                              where application_id in (select DISTINCT duplicate.id 
                                    from application duplicate inner join application application
                                    on duplicate.document_id = application.document_id
                                    where duplicate.modify_date < application.modify_date)),
                                    
delete from application_person where application_person.person_id in (select person_id from person_ids);

delete from person where id in (select person_id from person_ids);
```

For second call of person_ids i have `Query failed: ERROR: relation "person_ids" does not exist`

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want to delete all persons that were had a duplicate application associated to them, even if they have other (non-deleted) applications?

Comment: Applications will be deleted in next statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am i doing wrong?

You have two separate statements. The `person_ids` is only in scope within the first one, which lasts until the semicolon.

You'll want to use

```
WITH duplicate_applications AS (
  select DISTINCT duplicate.id 
  from application duplicate
  inner join application application using (document_id)
  where duplicate.modify_date < application.modify_date)
), deleted_persons AS (
  delete from application_person
  where application_id in (select application_id from duplicate_applications)
  returning person_id
)
delete from person
where id in (select person_id from deleted_persons);
```